# Common potential in Capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, capacitance, voltage

If two isolated charged capacitors (of different capacitance) are connected in parallel to each other they acquire a common potential. But suppose if i connect positive plate of one capacitor to negative plate of another capacitor will they still acquire a common potential or will the charge acquired by two capacitors be same as the circuit looks like that the capacitors are connected in series in which -ve plate of capacitors is connected to + ve plate of another capacitors

Comment: Any two pieces of metal that you connect together will quickly reach the same potential. It has nothing to do with whether they're plates of capacitors or if you label them as positive or negative.

Comment: @ThePhoton suppose if connect 2 capacitors in series with a battery of  p.d V .If they are of different capacitance  they don't acquire same potential .Why is that?Even though -ve plate is connected with positive plate .Or do they acquire same pd?

Comment: The wire that connects them is at the same potential along its whole length. Be careful to distinguish the potential of a point in space from the potential difference between two points (like the two plates of a capacitor)

Comment: Just to clarify: are you just connecting two capacitors in series to a battery, or are you taking two isolated, charged capacitors and connecting them together but leaving the other ends of the capacitors connected to nothing?

Comment: isolated capacitors

Comment: @Who [Like the right diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdXze.gif) you mean?

Comment: @JohnRennie  first they are charged individually and then they are connected with each other without any battery (it's a closed circuit not an open one,not  like 2nd image)

Comment: @Who in that case it's just two capacitors in parallel, and the voltages will be equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about connecting positive to negative and negative to positive in a closed circuit with two charged capacitors, and nothing else, then you are creating a direct short which will drain both, heat the entire circuit, and may damage capacitors, and, or wires.

Comment: yes that's what i am asking

Comment: @Who, you started your question with the example of two isolated, charged capacitors that are then connected in parallel.  Note that this covers *both* the cases that (1) the capacitors are connected 'plus to plus, minus to minus' and (2) ' plus to minus, minus to plus'.  In either case, the capacitors are connected in parallel and the result is (ideally) an instantaneous redistribution of electric charge such that both capacitors have identical voltage across.  The only difference is the initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If positive plate is connected to negative still the process remains the same charge will flow untill two capacitor are at same potential.